# How do I make a modal out of this form?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I have developed a form and I want it to be hidden and when a user presses a button, it opens up. I am using html/css and js. I have built it on a separate folder and want to add it to an existing one. I want the form to be above the rest of the other page.
So you can get a glance at what I am doing, here is a video of my form, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUdo6w87rh4&ab_channel=TraversyMedia
Now I want that form to start hidden and open on a button click.

Here is my code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />




<div class="container" id="container">
<div class="form-container sign-up-container">
<form action="#">
<h1>MMT University</h1>
<span>Se registre para começar</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Repita a sua senha" />
<button>Registrar</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="form-container sign-in-container">
<form action="#">
<h1>Acessar</h1>

<span>Acesse a MMT University</span>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
<a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
<button>Acessar</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="overlay-container">
<div class="overlay">
<div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
  <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
  <p>Para continuar aprendendo, acesse a sua conta!</p>
  <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
</div>
<div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
  <h1>MMT University!</h1>
  <p>Se registre para entrar na melhor universidade trading do mundo.</p>
  <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registre-se</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="modal.js"></script>

<button href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" id="myBtn">Acessar</button>
    </body>
```

Here is my css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #f6f5f7;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: -20px 0 50px;
}


h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(220,52,52);
    background-color: rgb(220,52,52);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(220,52,52);
}

form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
    0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%, 49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}
.close {
  /* Position it in the top right corner outside of the modal */
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Close button on hover */
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)}
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}
.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    background:  #05031b;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #05031b, #05031b);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #05031b, #05031b);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}

footer p {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

footer i {
    color: red;
}

footer a {
    color: #3c97bf;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is a file I copied from the internet and kind of managed my buttons in order to follow those ids.
(the file's name is modal.js, that is the script I imported there.) (the main.js is an animation for the form)

Javascript file modal.js

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Set the `id` of the element you want to be the modal to `myModal` and it should work

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have tried that, I changed the container divs id to that. For some reason it still starts open up and when I press anywhere outside the form, nothing happens.

Comment: Clear your cache. Also, if your `myModal` id Element is below your JavaScript without using a `load` Event, it won't be defined. I would put all of your JavaScript in your head and use load Events.

Comment: @Tomas_Mota - see my answer, it should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things you should note:

In your HTML, you load `modal.js` *before* you define `myBtn`:

```
...
</div>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script> 
<script src="modal.js"></script> <--- Loading modal.js

<button href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" id="myBtn">Acessar</button> <--- defining myBtn
```

So when `modal.js` runs, the first thing it does is it looks for `myBtn`,

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
```

...which doesn't exist yet.

So, you should probably load `modal.js` either in the head (between the `<head>` tags) of the document or at the end to avoid these problems.

After you've added the id `myModal` to the container, the modal probably will load without clicking the button. That's because it was never hidden. You need to hide it either via JS or CSS. Here's an example with JS (you just set the display to none):

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
modal.style.display = "none";
```

Now it shouldn't show until you click the button. But to hide it when you click outside, you need to check if the place where you clicked was *not* (1) the modal, and (2) in the modal. This is relatively easy:

```
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (modal !== event.target && !modal.contains(event.target)) { // Evaluates to true if the modal is not the clicked element and the
    modal.style.display = "none";                                // modal does not contain the clicked element
    btn.style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

But this is what you currently have:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

This is checking if the clicked element *is* the modal, *then* closing it if that is the case. That's not what you want, so use the previous example instead

--

You can also add the code for opening the modal into this listener, simplifying the whole code (full code of modal.js):

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
modal.style.display = "none";

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");


// Handle clicks
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if(event.target.id == "myBtn") { // If the button is clicked, open the modal and hide the "open the modal" button
    modal.style.display = "block";
    btn.style.display = 'none'
  }
  else if (modal !== event.target && !modal.contains(event.target)) { // If the click is outside the modal, hide the modal and show the "open the modal" button
    modal.style.display = "none";
    btn.style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

[Full example online](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/WeakFlashyVariety#index.html)

[image: demo]

Let me know if there are any problems you encounter with this solution.

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you so much man!!! Have a nice day

Comment: Man, I just have one more question, how do I add this to another file I have??

Comment: I have added a specific question to it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480230/how-to-add-a-modal-to-an-existing-file

If you could give it a look.

Comment: @Tomas_Mota - Sure, I'll take a look later today, (not sure what timezone you are in, but it is morning where I am), when I've got a chance.

Comment: Thank you my man, Im from Portugal, it is currently 2 pm. Hheeh, whenever you can. Have a nice one