# How to add a modal to an existing file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have successfully made a modal yesterday, separately, because I did not want to ruin the rest of my code. How do I add it to the existing one now? Here are the coding files. Thank you.

I have tried placing the modal code after the nav, but it just broke the whole website. The form showed up, just without the CSS.

Here is where I want to put the modal, I want it to open when I click the anchor tag "Acessar". I don't know where to put it, since the button who is going to open it is inside the navbar (yes, the button is the anchor tag, still have to change that).

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
          <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
        </label>
    <img src="logo-solo.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#quem-somos">Quem somos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#onde-atuamos">Onde  Atuamos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#servicos">Servicos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Depoimentos">Depoimentos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Comecando">comecando</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sac">Contacte-nos</a></li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/mmtuniversity_oficial/" class="fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuf2KhhA8Ub3hcSgfaziiDw" class="fa fa-youtube" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="cta" rel="modal:open" href="#ex1" key="login" id="myBtn">Acessar</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
      anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <section class="container3" id="home">
    <h1><strong>Bem-vindo à MMT UNIVERSITY</strong></h1>
    <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,<br> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi <br> ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore <br> deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h2>
  </section>
```

Here is my modal code (ps: the last line, the button, is to be changed by the one on the navbar)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<div id="myModal">
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
      <form action="#">
        <h1>MMT University</h1>
        <span>Se registre para começar</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repita a sua senha" />
        <button>Registrar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
      <form action="#">
        <h1>Acessar</h1>

        <span>Acesse a MMT University</span>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
        <a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
        <button>Acessar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-container">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
          <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
          <p>Para continuar aprendendo, acesse a sua conta!</p>
          <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
          <h1>MMT University!</h1>
          <p>Se registre para entrar na melhor universidade trading do mundo.</p>
          <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registre-se</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="modal.js"></script>

<button href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" id="myBtn">Acessar</button>
```

Also, do I just paste the CSS of the modal file into these ones?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

This is what my code looks like

https://repl.it/repls/VastGorgeousPlot#index.html

I the modals button are not accessible, I cannot close it and the whole body becomes a modal behind this container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image: demo]

If so, then it should be relatively easy. First you need to combine the modal HTML with the rest of your code. It'd probably make sense to add it to the end of the main page, after the `<section>`. You don't have to add the two `<script>` tags, and `<link>` tag though, unless they are different from what is in the main page already.

To make the modal nice looking, you need to place it in a container, which fills the entire page, and has a sort of faded background, like this:

[image: example1]

Notice how the background of the modal is greyed out somewhat. This highlights the modal nicely.

To do this, we wrap the div `myModal` in another div, which I'm going to call `modalContainer`. We'll apply some styles to it to get that desired background, so we also need to add a CSS class (I'm going to give this class the very clever name of `modal`). So you have this sort of structure:

```html
<body>
    ... everything before the modal on the main page ...
    <div id="modalContainer" class="modal">
        <div id="myModal" class="container">
            ... modal stuff goes here
        </div>
    </div>
    ... scripts and whatnot after the modal ...
</body>
```

And the CSS for this:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;    /* position it so that fills the screen, but doesn't move with the page (when you scroll, it doesn't move, but the page moves in the background) */
  top: 0;             /* position this element at the top...                  */
  left: 0;            /* ...left corner of the page...                        */
  width: 100%;        /* ...and set both the width                            */
  height: 100%;       /* ...and height to 100%, so that the element fills the entire screen */
  z-index: 99999;     /* set the z-index to a high enough number so that this element is positioned on top of all other elements */
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* set the background to black with some transparency, so you can see through it */

  /* The following simply centers the modal within this container */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

So, `modalContainer` spans the complete height and width of the screen and is the background for the modal, while `myModal` houses the actual modal.

Now, to function properly, this requires some changes to modal.js, namely in opening the modal container, instead of just the modal:

```js
//Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var modal_container  = document.getElementById("modalContainer")
modal_container.style.display = "none";


window.onclick = function (event) {
  console.log(event.target)
  if(event.target.id == "myBtn") { // If the button is clicked, open the modal container
    modal_container.style.display = "flex"
  }
  else if (modal !== event.target && !modal.contains(event.target)) { // If the click is outside the modal, hide the modal container
    modal_container.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Now it should work as desired.

Full HTML code:

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
          <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
        </label>
    <img src="logo-solo.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#quem-somos">Quem somos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#onde-atuamos">Onde  Atuamos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#servicos">Servicos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Depoimentos">Depoimentos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Comecando">comecando</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sac">Contacte-nos</a></li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/mmtuniversity_oficial/" class="fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuf2KhhA8Ub3hcSgfaziiDw" class="fa fa-youtube" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="cta" rel="modal:open" href="#ex1" key="login" id="myBtn">Acessar</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
      anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <section class="container3" id="home">
    <h1><strong>Bem-vindo à MMT UNIVERSITY</strong></h1>
    <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,<br> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi <br> ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore <br> deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h2>
  </section>

  <div class="modal" id="modalContainer">
      <div class="container" id="myModal">
        <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
          <form action="#">
            <h1>MMT University</h1>
            <span>Se registre para começar</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repita a sua senha" />
            <button>Registrar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
          <form action="#">
            <h1>Acessar</h1>

            <span>Acesse a MMT University</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
            <a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
            <button>Acessar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-container">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
              <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
              <p>Para continuar aprendendo, acesse a sua conta!</p>
              <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
              <h1>MMT University!</h1>
              <p>Se registre para entrar na melhor universidade trading do mundo.</p>
              <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registre-se</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="modal.js"></script>

</body>
```

[Run and edit this code online](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/WeakFlashyVariety-1/#index.html)

**EDIT:** (for the problem mentioned in the comments, which has been deleted by SO)

There are a couple of problems with what you have.

1. You aren't including the stylesheet, style.css (I'm not sure what it is named where you actually have your code, but in repl.it, the stylesheet is named style.css)

Fixing that results in:

[image: after edit step 1]

...but the modal is stuck at the bottom left:

[image: modal after 1]

2. Deciding to name the modal container class `modal` was a dumb idea on my part, because jQuery seems to already have reserved that name and is overriding it with its own styles. I should've seen that. Anyways, renaming it to `modal-container` and updating the HTML accordingly fixes this problem, but now the modal spans the *entire* page:

[image: modal after edit step 2]

3. That's because the `container` class isn't included for some reason on your style.css. I pasted it over, because it is a required class to structure the modal correctly:

[image: modal after edit step three]

4. You might have noticed that the right side of the modal's padding is messed up. This because of the padding rule in the class `overlay-panel`. Removing this results in:

[image: finished]

And all should be good now.

Repl.it link: https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/UncommonIntentMolecule-1

Comment: Hey man, first of all, thank you very much for taking some time off to answer my question. I have  added all of that to my code and the modal is now opening, however I think I have screwed something up. It is only opening in the bottom of the page. I think I have some error inside my css... https://repl.it/repls/UncommonIntentMolecule#index.html Here is the link for you to see what is happening.

Comment: Hi @TomasMota, I've edited my answer above to show the steps I took to resolve this. It should work, but let me know if there was something I missed.

Comment: I have added your code and even have edited my question. The modal is opening up, but the rest of the body is becoming a modal too, I added a link to my code and the following preview after the "EDIT" Section

Comment: @TomasMota - the causes of this are your two jQuery modal imports: `jquery.modal.min.css` and `jquery.modal.min.js`. If you are already implementing your own modal, why do you need them? Removing those two fixes the problem. You can see the scripts at lines 16-17 here: https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/VastGorgeousPlot#index.html

Comment: awesome dude, that fixed the problem, one minor detail, the modal stopped working, like, the animation on the button click. Any guesses?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...are you talking about animation on the buttons *themselves*, or some animation on the actual *modal*? It seems like the buttons on the page all work fine so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean on the modal itself, when you click on the right red button it is supposed to have an animation, described inside the main.js 

 I am guessing it has to do with where I positioned the script for that file, however I tried putting it inside the head tag an nothing happened.

Comment: Okay, but note that here: https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/VastGorgeousPlot#index.html you need to actually add the file main.js to the files...it's not there right now, so it can't be used.

Comment: Oh yes I know that and I have all of the files added, main.js and modal.js. I know this because that animation was working not so long ago, like this morning.

Comment: Can you share the repl link you're working on so I can take a look?

Comment: Yes of course, https://repl.it/repls/ShowyUnfitApplications#index.html.

I have added all of the js files, so you can take a better look, that is 100% of what I am working with

Comment: Does [this](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/ShowyUnfitApplications#main.js) solve your problem? I did two things. (1): remove this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>` from the document head, since it's loaded before the buttons it looks for are rendered, and placed it at the end of the document instead. And, (2), in line 3 of main.js I changed the container id from `container` to `myModal`, since that's what we changed it to, when implementing the modal earlier.

Comment: I tried that but it still didnt do anything... Thank you though

Comment: Wait, how is that possible? I directly modified your repl only in those two ways (removing the loading of main.js at line 9 in the html, but keeping it at the bottom of the html code, and changing `.getElementById('container');` to `.getElementById('myModal');` in line 3 of main.js) and it works for me. [Here is a screen capture I took that demonstrates it](https://i.gyazo.com/daef8ae35d1379d960a400964928b884.gif)

Comment: Man never mind, it was my bad, I was copying the code to my sheets and forgot to change the container to myModal.... ahahah my bad.
Thank you so much, you saved the day. Have a great day my dude.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.